# More Pythonic approach to functions in Python

Tags: python-2.7, architecture, module

I am making a small (I hope it is) project, and, of course, I use self-made functions. Is it better (more Pythonic) to move them to separate file(s) and import it(them), or just leave them in same file? Details about my project:
Uses NumPy, pyBrain, PIL. Based on my home computer. Basically just experiments with neural networks recognising digits. Current algorithm:

1. Generate a set of pictures containing digits
2. Make them fit my requirements (normalising them)
3. Putting them into NN friendly form
4. Training my NN them
5. Taking user's input (a picture with drawn digit)
6. Same as step 2+3, but for input received in 5
7. Feeding t into NN
8. Observing results.

Steps 1,2,3,6 contain functions. Total about 4-5 functions.

Comment: We need more info. Is it going to be just a bit of python code? Is it going to be a webproject? Using what framework? What is "small" for you? For a small project, a sophisticated structure usually doesn't pay off.

Comment: I would advise not to introduce extra code complexity for such a small project. All of these functions seem to be a part of a single module and that is fine from point of view.